# Parent div's height is larger than his children

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar, justify

I have one div which contains an ul tag and a span tag to creat my justified horizontal navbar.

The second span is an hidden span because i wanna the text of the first span is justified.

So, the problem i have now that, the parent div'height is larger than his children's height.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
    <ul id="span1">
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>DEF</li>
        <li>GHI</li>
        <li>JKL</li>
    </ul>
    <span id="span2"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#div1 {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 15px;
}
#div1 ul#span1 {
    display: inline;
    background-color: blue;
}
#div1 ul#span1 li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#div1 #span2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/blck/7sN24/)**

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Another question: I want to add a separate circle between two words like that: [image: Horizontal menu]

How can i do? Thanks!!!

**EDIT**: For my first question, thanks for @Leth0_, i've just changed height = 15px and it worked. Please give me some suggestions for my second question! THANKS!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7sN24/4/ This isn't fluid at all but it's a quick hack at your second question, I'll add it to my answer. I'd recomend working out a more fluid soloution if this is for a production website however this will do if it's for just yourself.

Comment: Not really, but with your help, i found the correct way. Thanks a lot! http://jsfiddle.net/blck/7sN24/7/

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try manually setting the height, try adding...

`height:20px` to the parent.

Comment: Yes it works!! Thanks! Can you give me some ideas for my second question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7sN24/2/)

```
#div1 {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
}
#div1 #span1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#div1 #span2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: green;
}
```